# Check whether daylight savings is on or off

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dst

In a scenario, I have to check whether daylight savings is in effect or not. Based on the outcome of the check, I have to do some calculations in a SQL server procedure.

What is the best way to quickly check if daylight savings is currently in effect?

Comment: Do you mean whether DST is in effect on the server, or in some other given time zone?

Comment: Yes, want to check on the Server

Comment: If ever time zones (including DST transitions) start to become important in a database, it's usually a sign to me that the database ought to just be storing everything in UTC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this [Daylight Savings Time Functions in SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1372/daylight-savings-time-functions-in-sql-server/) that is created by Tim Cullen.

Specifically, the code that I used was:

**Start Date Function**

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_GetDaylightSavingsTimeStart]
(@Year varchar(4))
RETURNS smalldatetime
as
begin
declare @DTSStartWeek smalldatetime, @DTSEndWeek smalldatetime
set @DTSStartWeek = '03/01/' + convert(varchar,@Year)
return case datepart(dw,@DTSStartWeek)
when 1 then
dateadd(hour,170,@DTSStartWeek)
when 2 then
dateadd(hour,314,@DTSStartWeek)
when 3 then 
dateadd(hour,290,@DTSStartWeek)
when 4 then 
dateadd(hour,266,@DTSStartWeek)
when 5 then 
dateadd(hour,242,@DTSStartWeek)
when 6 then 
dateadd(hour,218,@DTSStartWeek)
when 7 then
dateadd(hour,194,@DTSStartWeek)
end
end
```

**End Date Function**

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_GetDaylightSavingsTimeEnd]
(@Year varchar(4))
RETURNS smalldatetime
as
begin
declare @DTSEndWeek smalldatetime
set @DTSEndWeek = '11/01/' + convert(varchar,@Year)
return case datepart(dw,dateadd(week,1,@DTSEndWeek))
when 1 then
dateadd(hour,2,@DTSEndWeek)
when 2 then
dateadd(hour,146,@DTSEndWeek)
when 3 then
dateadd(hour,122,@DTSEndWeek)
when 4 then
dateadd(hour,98,@DTSEndWeek)
when 5 then 
dateadd(hour,74,@DTSEndWeek)
when 6 then 
dateadd(hour,50,@DTSEndWeek)
when 7 then 
dateadd(hour,26,@DTSEndWeek)
end
end
```

I then use the functions like this in my query:

```
declare @DLSStart smalldatetime 
, @DLSEnd smalldatetime 
, @DLSActive tinyint 
set @DLSStart = (select MSSQLTIPS.dbo.fn_GetDaylightSavingsTimeStart(convert(varchar,datepart(year,getdate()))))
set @DLSEnd = (select MSSQLTIPS.dbo.fn_GetDaylightSavingsTimeEnd(convert(varchar,datepart(year,getdate())))) 

if @Date between @DLSStart and @DLSEnd 
begin 
set @DLSActive = 1 
end 
else 
begin 
set @DLSActive = 0 
end 
select @DLSActive
```

Comment: Hi.  Just wanted to provide a warning about this old answer.  The solution encodes the DST rules for the USA.  Since those [might soon be changing](https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/15/politics/senate-daylight-saving-time-permanent/index.html), one should not rely on hard-coded rules like that.  Modern SQL Server can use [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql) instead.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In Western Europe, the summer time starts the last Sunday of March at 02:00

```
select 
DATEADD(
    day,
    DATEDIFF(
        day,
        '1900-01-07',
        DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,concat(year(getdate()),'-03-01')),30)
        )/7*7,
    '1900-01-07 02:00'
    ) as SummerTimeStarts
```

and ends the last Sunday of October at 03:00

```
Select 
DATEADD(
    day,
    DATEDIFF(
        day,
        '1900-01-07',
        DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,concat(year(getdate()),'-10-01')),30)
        )/7*7,
    '1900-01-07 03:00'
    ) as SummerTimeEnds
```

It gives as en function :

```
CREATE function [dbo].[DateIsSummerTime]
(@datetime datetime)
RETURNS bit
as
begin
    declare @SummerTimeStarts datetime, @SummerTimeEnds datetime
    set @SummerTimeStarts = (select DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'1900-01-07',DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,concat(year(getdate()),'-03-01')),30))/7*7,'1900-01-07 02:00'))
    set @SummerTimeEnds   = (Select DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'1900-01-07',DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,concat(year(getdate()),'-10-01')),30))/7*7,'1900-01-07 03:00')) 

    Return  Case when @datetime > @SummerTimeStarts and @datetime < @SummerTimeEnds then 1 else 0 end
end
```